# How to sort a nested dictionary value numerically?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, numeric, ordereddictionary

I have a nested dictionary depicting records of teams in a hockey league. In a hockey league, they have a points system that depicts the standings. I'm wanting to sort the dictionary by the points values. The point system is the ((total wins*2)+(overtime losses))

```
standings =
    [
        {'Memphis': {'20-11-16': 56 PTS}},
        {'Seattle': {'10-25-10': 30 PTS}},
        {'Boston': {'35-0-10': 80 PTS}},
        {'Dallas': {'25-15-0': 50 PTS}}
    ]
```

Desired Outcome when printed

```
[
    {'Boston': {35-0-10: 80 PTS}},
    {'Memphis': {20-11-16: 56 PTS}},
    {'Dallas': {25-15-0: 50 PTS}},
    {'Seattle': {10-25-10: 30 PTS}}
]
```

How can I sort the dictionary so that the standings are in numerical order according to the PTS value, from highest to lowest? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your example is not a valid python dictionary. And dictionaries are not good for sorted data, use a list.

Comment: It's a list of objects. Just sort it with a suitable key function (presumably points) and you should be good. Can't help you beyond that, since the question isn't valid.

Answer (score 3):

Something like that:

```
✗ ipython
Python 3.8.1 (default, Dec 30 2019, 04:38:13)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.9.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: standings = [{'Memphis': {'20-11-16': 56}}, {'Seattle': {'10-25-10': 30}}, {'Boston': {'35-0-10': 80}}, {'Dallas': {'25-15-0': 50}}]

In [2]: sorted(standings, key=lambda x: list(list(x.values())[0].values())[0])
Out[2]:
[{'Seattle': {'10-25-10': 30}},
 {'Dallas': {'25-15-0': 50}},
 {'Memphis': {'20-11-16': 56}},
 {'Boston': {'35-0-10': 80}}]

In [3]: sorted(standings, key=lambda x: list(list(x.values())[0].values())[0], reverse=True)
Out[3]:
[{'Boston': {'35-0-10': 80}},
 {'Memphis': {'20-11-16': 56}},
 {'Dallas': {'25-15-0': 50}},
 {'Seattle': {'10-25-10': 30}}]

In [4]:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the print output, then you can just do a lambda sort. If, for whatever reason, you actually want the dictionary to maintain the order, then you should consider using `collections.OrderedDict`
It's worth mentioning that a dictionary is intrinsically unordered, so you should consider using another data format.